# Are syntax errors raised in JavaScript during Tokenizing or Parsing?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, v8

Are syntax errors raised in JavaScript during Tokenizing or Parsing?
And are ReferenceErrors thrown during Code generation?

Comment: What about you give it a try?

Comment: `"is this during parsing"?! && undefinedFunction("comes later") && knownFunction(unknownVariable, "comes even later")`...but in reality it's not so straight (and optimizations will make things even more complex).

Comment: *"Are syntax errors raised in JavaScript during Tokenizing or Parsing?"* Looks like the parser throws the syntax errors (try to run `5foo`). However, that is most likely implementation specific. A ReferenceError can actually be thrown at parse time and runtime ([proof](http://jsfiddle.net/crhv3y09/)) (there is something called "early errors").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are syntax errors raised in JavaScript during Tokenizing or Parsing?

The tokenizer is a part of the parser, so the answer is *yes*.

> And are ReferenceErrors thrown during Code generation?

Some ReferenceErrors are thrown *before code is evaluated* (if that is what you mean by "code generation").

The [ES5 spec](http://es5.github.io/#x16) is quite clear about that:

> *An implementation must report most errors at the time the relevant
>   ECMAScript language construct is evaluated. An **early error** is an
>   error that can be detected and reported prior to the evaluation of any
>   construct in the Program containing the error. […]
>   All errors that are not early errors are runtime errors.*
>
> *An implementation must treat any instance of the following kinds of
>   errors as an early error:*
>
> - *[…]*
> - *Attempts to call PutValue on any value for which an early
>     determination can be made that the value is not a Reference (for
>     example, executing the assignment statement `3=4`).*

Comment: Actually the tokenizer is part of the compiler http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~pjj/farrell/comp3.html and the parser just makes the "Tree" from the tokens. Although I do see now that Reference Errors are thrown at either in Early errors points.

Comment: Ah, I see, you can view them as distinct parts of the compiler, and have a stream of tokens as the input of the parser. Regardless, syntax errors can happen at different stages of the process: The tokenizer is not able to recognize a token, the parser cannot put a token into the parse tree, or the code generator/interpret realizes that the tree is invalid (describes invalid code). How much (or: which) logic you want in each step is just a compiler design decision. I'm not sure how V8 does it.